# Is random.random() the same as random.uniform()?

Tags: python, random

What is the difference between python's [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.random) method and [`random.uniform()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.uniform) method?

Are the result from `random.random()` not uniformly distributed?

```
import random

print(random.random() * 10)
print(random.uniform(0,10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of `random.uniform` from the [`random.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l342) module:

```
def uniform(self, a, b):
    return a + (b-a) * self.random()
```

So, yes, it's the same distribution.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), `random.random()` returns a number in the range [0, 1.0), when `random.uniform(a,b)` returns a number in range [a,b] or [a,b), depending on floating-point rounding in equation `a + (b-a) * random()`.

So both `print(random.random() * 10)` and `print(random.uniform(0,10))` can give you the same distribution.